# xcode build error

Tags: c++, xcode, build

Command /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
build error

My project was working fine with no errors, and  I went to run it again without changing anything and received this error (only this). Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when certain .cpp files didn't exist, but it could be caused by any number of things. Clearly in your case it's something different, if you're sure you haven't changed anything in the project.

On the right of the build results list there should be a (well hidden) button with lines - that shows the raw build output, which should give you some idea about what went wrong.  What does that say?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I actually just tried running with a few my previous c++ programs and received the same error. In this case it would be an xcode problem right?

Comment: It could be, or it could be gcc itself.  The raw build output is the only thing that will really tell you what happened.